# Enable IOMMU for Xenserver

Tags: xenserver

I have installed Xenserver 6.2 in my machine with ASUS A58M-E motherboard and AMD A8-6600K APU (CPU). Now even if the IOMMU is enabled in the BIOS, Xenserver is reporting that IOMMU is not enabled and thus Virtual Machines cannot take advantage of the Radeon HD of the APU.

What is the correct way to make IOMMU with Xenserver and to allow GPU assignments for Virtual machines running in the Xenserver machine.

Comment: Display is very slow without IOMMU

Comment: Have you tried upgrade to Xenserver 6.5. ?